# Can't seem to pass multiple arguments into bash script

Tags: bash, shell, script, shell-script

I have 3 bash scripts.

`firstScript.sh` that calls `secondScript.sh` that calls `thirdScript.sh`

`firstScript.sh` is executed like this in the terminal: `firstScript.sh test1 test2`
From `firstScript.sh`, I call `secondScript.sh` passing in `$1` and `$2` for the respective test1 and test2 like this:
`sh secondscript.sh $1 $2`

`secondScript.sh` runs fine, and calls `thirdScript.sh` like this:

`sh thirdScript.sh $1 $2 > logs/thirdScript_$1_.txt 2>&1`

This seems to be a problem, `thirdScript.sh` is not able to get variable $2.

I need some help troubleshooting this, as I may have the wrong syntax.

Comment: It will be hard to solve your problem without actual code.

Comment: First, run your scripts through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fix what it finds -- at the very least, you're missing double-quotes around parameter references (e.g. use `"$1"` instead of just `$1`), which can cause weird problems. If that doesn't solve it, you can put `set -x` just before the troublesome command(s) to tell bash to print *its* interpretation of what's going on (to standard error, so if you redirect that to a log, look there), and see what's different from what you expect.

Comment: some points of attention: `sh` is not the same as `bash` and you should quote your variables as in `bash thirdScript.sh "$1" "$2" > logfile 2>&1` . If things fail, put `echo` statements for debugging to be sure about the contents of variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a guess work than helping without actual code.
Considering your question, I can think of below steps ...

1. Make sure you are using shift in a correct way in your second shell script (of course if you are using it.)
2. Print $2 before calling "thirdScript.sh $1 $2" in second script. And also print the value of $2 at the very beginning of the thirdSrcipt.sh. It will help you identify the script which has problem.

Hope it helps you troubleshoot you scripts.
Happy troubleshooting